# AJAX function not working when placed inside a plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a simple AJAX function that I've placed inside my theme's functions.php. It works, and "working" is returned correctly to the jQuery ajax request, so that side of things is fine.

BUT, when the same function is placed into a plugin instead, it no longer works, just returns 0.

```
function addCustomer(){

    echo "working";
    die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addCustomer', 'addCustomer');
```

I also tried placing the action hook inside an 
    if ( is_admin() )
as was suggested in [this tutorial](http://flav36rs.com/2011/09/12/using-front-end-ajax-requests-in-your-wordpress-plugins/), but no luck.

I think I'm probably overlooking something incredibly obvious, but I can't figure it out. Any help appreciated, because I've been googling for hours now.

EDIT: Here's the AJAX call I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery('#newCustomerForm').submit(ajaxSubmit); 

                        function ajaxSubmit(){

                            var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

                            jQuery.ajax({
                                type:"POST",
                                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                                data: newCustomerForm,
                                success:function(data){
                                    jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
                                },
                                error: function(errorThrown){
                                    alert(errorThrown);
                                }   
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
```

but I'm certain this bit is fine, as it's working perfectly when the receiving function is placed in functions.php, just not when placed in a separate plugin.

Comment: You should read the article you linked too and do it the way they are doing it.  That is the right way.

Comment: Well, there's quite a difference between the simplistic code I'm posting and how the linked article has done it. Specifically I'd like to know what exactly they've done that makes it work - I'm fairly certainly making the whole thing a class is good programming, but not neccessary. Is the fact that I don't have a nonce check blocking it? And if so, why would it work in the functions, but not in the plugin?

Comment: are you sure you're not receiving the data?  Have you tried to call the ajax call using a rest client so you can see what's returned?  Datatype is probably expecting a json return and you're using a print statement, so that could be a factor.  Show us what your AJAX call code looks like so that we can see both halves of the problem.

Comment: Edited to add that, but I already said, it works as expected when placed in functions.php, just not when inside a plugin - I'm missing some key part that's breaking it within the context of a plugin. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too but when running in debug (firebug) I got a 404 error, the url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" was missing. To fix this change it to url section as below:

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
 var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
 jQuery.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: newCustomerForm,
  success:function(data){
   jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
  },
  error: function(errorThrown){
   alert(errorThrown);
  }   
 });
 return false;
}
```

and it should work

VK

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar issue. The Ajax function was working when placed in function.php and not when inside a plugin.

Turns out it was because of W3 Total Cache, after purging all cache solved the issue.